# XMLHttpRequest skip readyState

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy, pastebin

Problem with posting data via `XMLHttpRequest`.

For [GitHub Gist](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/) this works successfully:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=
        this.readyState + " " + this.status + "<br>";
};

var data = {
  "public": true,
  "files": {
    "file_name.txt": {
      "content": "Hello, world!"
    }
  }
}

xhr.open("POST", "https://api.github.com/gists", true);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Output:

```
1 0
2 201
3 201
4 201
```

Where 201 - code of success.

But for [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/api) this code shows unexpected behavior: after state 1 (OPENED) jumps to state 4 (DONE).

```js
try {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=
            this.readyState + " " + this.status + "<br>";
    };

    xhr.open("POST", "http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php", true);
    xhr.send();

} catch (err) {
    window.alert(err.message);
}
```

Output:

```
1 0
4 0
```

I had read about Same-Origin policy and consider that it might be reason of my problem. It is true? Can it be fixed for interactions with pastebin.com? Thanks!

Comment: Update: found worked service: [Friendpaste](https://friendpaste.com/). Easy to post and update without account identifications (just by document's id what I was looking for). Thank you guys for upvoting this topic.